# Using a docker container querying an AWS RDS Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-aurora

I am developing an application that is going to be deployed using a docker container. This app connect and queries a Aurora database on AWS RDS.

I would like to make some QA tests, pointing to test database instead of Aurora db production.

What is the best approach?

Create a database replica on the same RDS ?

Put and MySQL instance inside the app container and point to it, and make the QA tests?

Or create a simple container with MySQL installed and points my app to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Put and MySQL instance inside the app container

That is generally not advised, as a container is supposed to represent a service in a fixed state, and should not change during runtime.

> create a simple container with MySQL installed and points my app to it?

That is closer, although, if possible, I would again not change the existing running app container, but launch a new app one, with --link to a test MySQL container.
That way, you keep separate whatever prod runtime environment from your test environment.

Comment: Thanks VonC! So i am going to have tow containers: One for MySQL instance and other for my app. Am I rigth?

Comment: @PedroMagalhaes yes, one container per service (one for app, one for database) sounds right.

Comment: I think it's make sense to use 2 containers per service(one container with service plus [data-only container](http://container42.com/2013/12/16/persistent-volumes-with-docker-container-as-volume-pattern/)).

Comment: @atomdev I agree. Isolating data in a data volume container is generally a best practice.